# UK MBA keyboard layout vs Apple external keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard

This question is not about remapping keyboard layouts and different languages. This is about the actual differences in the physical location of keys.

My June 2011 UK Macbook Air has the same keyboard layout I'm used to from previous Macbooks - a double height return key and the backtick/tilde key inbetween left-shift and Z.

I recently got to Australia and bought an external keyboard in the Apple store, not realising the physical layout would be different. The keyboard looks like this:

http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB110Z/B

I want to get an external keyboard which matches my Macbook Air - which I guess would be the external wireless keyboard. Unfortunately, even the Apple Store suggests the layout of the "British" one is not what I'm expecting:

http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC184B/B

Can anyone explain if/when the keyboards changed? Is is possible for me to get an external keyboard with the same layout as my MBA?

Thanks y'all

Comment: What does your MBA keyboard look like? The photos you show here, are the same keyboard layouts as the new MBP and MB. There is no double hight return key: http://cl.ly/Ccqw/overview_gallery2_20111024.png

Comment: @Matt New laptops sold with the British (or other ISO) layout do have a two-row return key.

Comment: Here's a pic of my MBA keyboard: http://s11.postimage.org/wo4294tlf/IMAG0040.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the extra key to the left of the z, you should get that with any "ISO" keyboard sold in Europe.  In the US, keyboards are "ANSI" and are missing that key.  Other countries may vary.  See this note:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2841

Comment: The difference between ISO and ANSI certainly makes sense - but the link you posted doesn't make that distinction. Both the British and International keyboards on there are the same.

Comment: Indeed they are the same.  If you actually have a keyboard without the extra key, it is not either British or International, both of which are ISO, but a US Ansi keyboard.  I can only guess that there is a mismatch between the label and the photo.

Comment: Minor update - I had one imported from the UK store, it's as I desired :D

Answer (score 1):

The pictures in the Apple Store are just wrong. The picture below is of a US keyboard layout (or a layout similar to it), not the British one that's actually being sold:

[image]

The British layout should look like this:

[image]