# Do Apple provide a service to substitute MacBook key caps?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I would like to buy a used MacBook, but in the region I am located they are mainly sold in a different keyboard layout than the one I am used to. Can I ask apple to substitute the key caps for me (of course for a fee)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Hardware shopping is off topic here. If this is about something other than cost, could you edit it to be on topic?

Comment: As suggested, I edited the question to be on topic.

Comment: You forgot to take out the third party and DIY options. I’ve edited and reopened. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for “training” me, it was really nice of you. I hope that next time I get it right the first time.

Comment: You did great! The editing is collaborative  is a great thread that will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

[Apple keyboards are physically different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/difference-between-us-qwerty-and-international-qwerty-apple-keyboards/106059#106059) when you specify them at the time of order. Apple does not change out the layout as a service offering. They will repair a damaged keyboard or worn one in a way that you get the warranty on all Apple Authorized service, but this doesn’t include a transplant of a different layout than what was purchased.

I would budget for a new Apple Bluetooth keyboard in your purchase plans in case you can’t get used to the [different layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33757/uk-mba-keyboard-layout-vs-apple-external-keyboard-layouts) and a [wired one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/117062/5472) isn’t amenable to your workspace layout.

It takes me three weeks to get used to a new layout and mistakes abound and it never truly feels right for far longer, so if your brain works like mine, you’ll be unhappy if you need the key labels to match the layout until you’re rewired your typing expectations.